# Score for concordance of two classifications with different number of classes

Tags: classification, multilabel-classification, score

I am searching for a score to compare two different classifications of the same observations.

I was thinking about [Adjusted Rand Index](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.adjusted_rand_score.html#sklearn.metrics.adjusted_rand_score) or [Adjusted Mutual Information](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.adjusted_mutual_info_score.html), but the problem is that the first classification splits the observations in 4 classes, the second in 5 classes. If I understood these metrics correctly, the number of classes should be the same between the two classifications (only permutation of the labels is allowed).

The idea is that, if the score is between 0 (no concordance) to 1 (full concordance) I may get a result like this:

```
# permutation is ok  
score( [1,2,3,4], [2,1,3,4] )  =  1

# subset is ok
score( [1,2,3,4], [1,1,2,3] )  =  1

# this should be less than 1 (last item in the second classification
# may be 1,2 but not 3)
score( [1,1,2,1], [1,2,3,3] )  <  1
```

Is there a similar score to evaluate concordance of two classifications with different number of classes?